# Can I use a certificate to authenticate to a Rest API in Azure B2C policies?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to call a Rest API in a B2C Technical Profile. That is described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/restful-technical-profile

The Rest API is protected by Azure AD, and I need to first obtain a bearer token from Azure AD and use the `Bearer` `Authentication Type` in the Technical Profile to access the Rest API.

I want to use a certificate and not a secret to obtain a bearer token from Azure AD. To do so, I have to create a [JWT Assertion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-certificate-credentials) signed by the certificate. That process is described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#second-case-access-token-request-with-a-certificate

I understand that much. What I am not sure about is if B2C has any functionality for which I can build and sign a JWT Assertion to use in a request to Azure AD? I've looked through the claims transformations that are available and am not finding anything. Am I forced to use Client ID and Secret instead?

Answer (score 0):

Please **note** that, to generate JWT token with certificate you must create a **`self-signed certificate`** like below:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate 
    -KeyExportPolicy Exportable 
    -Subject "CN=yourappname.yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com" 
    -KeyAlgorithm RSA 
    -KeyLength 2048 
    -KeyUsage DigitalSignature 
    -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddMonths(12) 
    -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\CurrentUser\My"
```

[image]

On Windows computer, select  **Manage user certificates** and download the certificate:

[image]

Please **note** that, **`client_id`** is required to authentication Azure Ad b2c.

To upload the certificate, go to Azure Ad b2c and *select **API connectors** and upload certificate and create a Password* for it like below:

[image]

Make sure to configure REST API profile to use HTTP basic authentication by following this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/secure-rest-api?tabs=windows&pivots=b2c-custom-policy#configure-your-rest-api-technical-profile-to-use-http-basic-authentication).

To generate the token without **`client_secret`**, please try the below parameters:

[image]

And try generating the token and if you want to do it programmatically, then update your **appsettings** file like below:

```json
"B2CTenant": "Tenant_ID",
"B2CPolicy": "Policy_name",
"B2CClientId": "client_id",
"B2CRedirectUri": "redirecturi",
"B2CSignUpUrl": "Signup_url",
"SigningCertAlgorithm": "RS256",
"SigningCertThumbprint": "Thumbprint",
"LinkExpiresAfterMinutes": 10
```

**Reference:**

[Secure APIs used as API connectors in Azure AD B2C - Azure AD B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/secure-rest-api?tabs=windows&pivots=b2c-user-flow#option-2-prepare-a-self-signed-certificate-using-powershell-module)